# Order By sorts differently than Sort Transformation in SSIS (Integration services)

Tags: sql, sorting, ssis

Using SSIS I've encountered issues when joining due to sorting using two OLE DB Sources.

I've discovered that if I use an order by vs. a sort transformation it produces different results that causes a merge join to product incorrect data

Example:

Table1

```
Id int PK
JoinKey varchar(25)
OriginalValue varchar(25)
```

Table2

```
Id int PK
JoinKey varchar(25)
ExpectedValue varchar(25)
```

The Program Flow in SSIS is as follows:

1. OLE Data source selecting from Table1
2. Sort Transformation on Table1 by JoinKey asc then ExpectedValue asc
3. OLE Data source selecting from Table2 Order By JoinKey asc
4. Merge Join Transformation (left outer join) with Table1 and Table2 on JoinKey selecting OriginalValue and ExpectedValue

In doing this - I end up with a null value for ExpectedValue, for some of my data set. Doing the query directly in SQL returns the values expected.

If I add a Sort Transformation before step 5, it correctly joins the ExpectedValue however then SSIS has the warning "Validation warning. The data is already sorted as specified so the transform can be removed."

Two questions:

1. Shouldn't using an order by and a sort transformation produce the same results?
2. Why does SSIS indicate a warning when the sort is actually needed?

I've browse some related posts but they seem to focus on efficiency not differences in functionality.

1. [Is it better to sort data at the application layer, or with an order by clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173673/is-it-better-to-sort-data-at-the-application-layer-or-with-an-order-by-clause/18175516#18175516)
2. [why we need to use sort transformation before merge join transformation in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919512/why-we-need-to-use-sort-transformation-before-merge-join-transformation-in-ssis)
3. [SQL Server Integration Service Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656932/sql-server-integration-service-left-join)

Comment: Run these two queries against Server 1(table 1's source) and Server 2(table 2's source) `SELECT D.name, D.collation_name FROM sys.databases AS D WHERE d.name IN ('tempdb', 'MyDatabase');` and 
`SELECT C.name, C.collation_name FROM sys.schemas AS S INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id INNER JOIN sys.columns AS C ON C.object_id = T.object_id WHERE S.name = N'MySchema' AND T.name = 'MyTable' AND C.name = N'JoinKey';`

Comment: All of the results are   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Well that's no good. Now I have to think of another scenario. (future readers, my assumption was we had case sensitivity one Db and not the other or had a character set - been bitten by both of those before)

Comment: The actual value I am joining on is the string A-
I originally figured the - was the issue however other symbols such as / and  * seem to work fine with the above scenario

Comment: A quick check to ensure you're matching what you think you're matching is to compute a hash for the text. `CONVERT(varchar(34), CONVERT(varbinary(20), HASHBYTES('MD5', T.JoinKey)), 1) AS JoinKeyHashBytesASCII` Add that column to both sources and then use a data viewer to see what the computed hash is. Ought to be 0xF0412E3C4F9232CFC64F498344EE0749 but if you get something else, then you likely have white space issues with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced this in the past and the answer is NO, sorting with an ORDER BY in your Source SQL does not always produce the same results as using a Sort Transformation in your Dataflow task.  There is a difference in the way certain special (non alpha-numeric) characters (and maybe NULLS) are handled; I can't remember exactly which.   I don't recall finding any documentation about this (it was years ago), but I confirmed it through my own testing.

My conclusion was, to do a JOIN in the dataflow, make sure you use the same method of sorting on both sides of the JOIN.

As for your second question, SSIS has an IsSorted property on a datasource.  If you set the IsSorted property on the DataSource to true, then if you try to do a Sort Transformation, all it knows is that IsSorted is true and it will give the warning that sorting is not needed.  It doesn't know that the Sort Transformation is "needed" in order to match another source that used a Sort Transformation.

If you want to use Sort Transformations on both sides of the JOIN, set the IsSorted property of your source to false.

Answer (score 1):

Found a Microsoft post indicating the reason. Marking Tab Alleman's response as the answer as it is what led me to finding this.

The Sort transformation uses Windows collation to sort string values.

You cannot use the ORDER BY clause alone because the ORDER BY clause uses a SQL Server collation to sort string values. The use of the SQL Server collation might result in a different sort order than Windows collation, which can cause the Merge or Merge Join transformation to produce unexpected results.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137653.aspx