# SSIS Sort large data from Heterogeneous sources - Alternatives

Tags: sorting, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am looking for alternatives to sort ~2 million records on SSIS.

Data sourced from Heterogeneous sources (SQL, Oracle, DB2) after applying multiple  transformation, there is an Union All to combine data and then needs to be sorted by three fields.

This is because data needs to be sorted by certain fields before we sent to external vendor

These are the solutions I already tried :

- Buffer size (100 MB) and Max rows tuning (50K rows)
- Applied sort at each source (Just for the sake of my mind !)
- Set Validate external metadata property to False (for Sort Trans)
- tried script task (C# sorting)

None of these significantly improved performance.

Is there any other alternatives ?

Update :
This is string sort on Three different fields which belongs to three different DB tables (SQL, Oracle, DB2). I can't sort until data set is combined.

- Tried loading output to a single table and used Order by with appropriate indexing  - This gives an unexpected result as SQL Order by behaves differently than Sort Transformation [Here is the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168900/order-by-sorts-differently-than-sort-transformation-in-ssis-integration-service)

Comment: Why do you need to sort? For a subsequent operation in SSIS? Please note these two points: 1. Databases do not store in sorted order. They store clustered index order. 2. Databases do not return in stored or inserted order, they return in `ORDER BY` order. You could try loading all into a single table and sorting, but what's the point - why are you sorting?

Comment: Try inserting them unsorted into a table that is indexed on your sort fields, and then select them from that table with an ORDER BY.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Data needs to be sorted by certain fields before we sent to external vendor.  I am getting expected results through Sort Transformation only, Order by is not as expected. Please refer update.

Comment: @TabAlleman : Order by and Sort transformation results are different. sort Transformation sort order is correct as per our business requirement.

Comment: If you choose the correct collation you'll probably get the sort you are after. SQL Server supports windows collations. Sorting is an expensive operation. If you want to do it in SSIS you'll just need to tune it - work out if any of the three sources are providing data too slow, work out if you are running out of memory etc.

Comment: Here's a list of possible _windows_ collations that you can set your varchar data to - you just need to work out which one it should be, then ensure the varchar columns are set to that then your order by should work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` transformation instead of `UNION ALL`:

Instead of using a `UNION ALL` to combine data sets first and then sorting the resulting large combined dataset, you are better to sort each smaller set first and then use a `MERGE` transformation. The result of the `MERGE` transformation will be already sorted.

Comment: This is string sort on Three different fields which belongs to three different DB tables (SQL, Oracle, DB2). I can't sort until data set is combined.